# Custom Setting List in a Special Settings Tab

Tags: apex, force.com

I would like to create a special "Settings" Tab in which users can customize their email templates and other information.

I would like to use Custom Setting List, and create a special "Setting" page and tab for that.

I have an issue with creating the tab, since the tab can be based on custom object or on web URL (outside of the force.com platform).

I guess I can create the tab based on related custom object, although that's seems to be a workaround I don't really like. Alternatively I can place the settings in existing screens I have today, although I do not like this solution as well.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: You should be able to create a Web Tab to point to a URL in salesforce as well, I would've thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a VisualForce tab, based on a VF page you define.
Setup | Tabs | New Visualforce Tab
You need to create at least a shell VF page first so that you can select it in the wizard

[image: VF Tab setup page 1]